# How to call a stored procedure to populate one table from another in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, insert

I am still new to SQL, so doing it by learning. I would like to populate a table using stored procedure. My question is how do I call the procedure so that it gets executed and the table gets populated. So far I have done this.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[MytestTableLoad]
   @ID int,
   @FirstName varchar,
As
Begin
   Set nocount on;

   merge dbo.MytestTable2 as target
   using (select @ID, @FirstName,@LastName) as source (Id, FirstName, LastName)
   on (target.Id=source.Id)
   when not matched then
     Insert   (Id, FirstName, LastName)
     values (@Id, @FirstName,@LastName)
   ;
END
```

Comment: Your Stored Procedure is missing the @LastName parameter declaration.

Answer (score 1):

An easier syntax would be;

```
insert into table2
(field1, field2, etc)
select field1, field2, etc
from SomeOtherTables
where not exists
(subquery to check for records you don't want.)
```

Answer (score 0):

"how do I call the procedure so that it gets executed and the table gets populated."

Like this:

```
EXEC MytestTableLoad 1,'Bob'
```

Comment: What about the parameters? :)

Comment: Thanks Electric. @David: in my requirement there is no parameter involves so I am good, thanks though

Comment: @poshan - that wasn't evident from your example :)

Comment: ? your stored proc definition takes parameters.